# Can you make a pre-existing .aspx page appear modally on another page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I hope that you can help with this problem.
I have two pages, page A contains a table of information from a SQL database, page B allows users to create new records.  I want to be able to have a button which displays page B modally rather than having to re-direct the user.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, there are many ways one of which is [jQuery UI Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default).

First, make sure you load jQuery UI in your page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Then, in page A:

```
<p><input type="button" class="button" value="Modal" /></p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.button').click(function () {
        var page = "PageB.aspx";

        var d = $('<div></div>')
            .html('<iframe src="' + page + '"></iframe>')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 350,
                width: 250,
                title: "Some title"
            });

        d.dialog("open");
    });
</script>
```